# How can i start a web server and update my function in one script

Tags: python, bottle

I start a server and use some data from my function. But I want this function to update data and display new one on my server. However when I start a web server it only takes the first compiled data from function.

I use "schedule" - imported library, that can schedule my task to compile my function in time i choose. Also bottle web framework to start server and make routing.

```
def read_file():
    f=open("345.txt", "r")
    hi.contents = f.read()
    print(hi.contents)

def server_start():
    @route('/as', method = 'GET')
    def display_status():
        try:
            return hi.contents
        except Exception:
            logging.exception("")
            return "Service unavailable. Check logs"
    run(host='0.0.0.0',  port=8033)
    print("sadq")

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(read_file)
server_start()

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I expect to get updated results on my web server. Would be very glad if you help me or give some good advices. Thak you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would run bottle with an async process, specifically gevent.

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, signal
monkey.patch_all()
from bottle import app
import scheduler

app = Bottle()

@route('/as', method = 'GET')
def display_status():
    try:
        return scheduler.contents
    except Exception:
        logging.exception("")
        return "Service unavailable. Check logs"

print("sadq")
server = WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", int(8083)), app)
def shutdown():
    print('Shutting down ...')
    server.stop(timeout=60)
    exit(signal.SIGTERM)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown) #CTRL C
server.serve_forever()
```

Then I would launch your scheduler as such in a separate file scheduler.py:

```
from gevent import spawn, sleep
import schedule

contents = ''
def read_file():
    global contents
    f=open("345.txt", "r")
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)    

def start_thread():
    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(read_file)
spawn(start_thread)
```

Comment: Oh big thanks there. It works fine. I am gonna read about "gevent" more and async programming. Anyway thank you for help.

Comment: Technically the schedule module has built in compatibility with gevent, so you don't need to spawn it in it's own greenlet.  I was just providing an example.

Comment: I LOVE the gevent library.  I use it for everything.